# Getting the connection string from an imported source

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, connection-string

I have added a new datasource from a SQL-server into my project and want to create a SQLConnection (using System.Data.SqlClient).

During the datasource creation I saved the Connectionstring as Dev_DBConnectionString and want to use this now but I have no clue how. I tried

```
ConsoleApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.masterConnectionString
```

(this is how some c# tutorials doing it) but get the error: Properties is not a Member of ConsoleApplication1. I have checked some vb.net tutorials ([e.g.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx)) but they are using the descriptive way like

```
Data Source=MSSQL1;Database=AdventureWorks;" & "Integrated Security=true;
```

But I guess that the string is already somewhere in my system. Anyone who can help me out here?

Comment: Check the App.config file to see if it is there. If it is then try My.Settings. and see if intellisense will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

**FIRST**

You have to setup your connection!

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data

Public Class SQLTools
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
    Private Const SqlString As String = Dev_DBConnectionString
    Private myConn As SqlConnection
    Private myCmd As SqlCommand
    Private myReader As SqlDataReader

    Private Sub Conn()
        myConn = New SqlConnection(SqlString)
    End Sub
```

**Now you can enjoy your DB connection**

It's time to do what you want! you just need to call `Conn()` to setup everything and than you have to open the connection using `MyConn.Open()`

**Dev_DBConnectionString problems**

You can always write it again.

*e.g.*

```
Private Const SqlString As String = "Server=****;Database=****;User ID=****;Password=****;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

Comment: I get "Dev_DWConnection" is not declared and System.Windows.Forms.Form is not defined.

Comment: you can go without `System.Windows.Forms.Form` as well.
Look at my comment for **Dev_DBConnectionString problems**